# Put values in Hashmap from external methods?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to do something like in this example. I can't figure out why it is not working. 
myMap has no value in the main class. But if I put the value in the "putSomethingInTheMap" into the map it has the right value in the main class.

Can you give me a suggestion how to handle something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> meineMap = new HashMap<>();
    int wert = 1;
    putSomethingInTheMap(meineMap, wert);
    System.out.println(meineMap.get("A"));
}

private static void putSomethingInTheMap(Map<String, Integer> myMap, int value) {
    myMap = insert(value);
}

private static Map<String, Integer> insert(int wert) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", wert);
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void putSomethingInTheMap(Map<String, Integer> myMap, int value) {
    myMap.put("A", wert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing it method `pass by refrence` . In main class your creating a map and passing it to `putSomethingInTheMap` where it is assigned by the map returned by `insert`.
So if you have value in main class it is due to refrence passed to method.

Answer (score 0):

Because meineMap reference is same as original. You declared a new reference with new value in *insert* method, and java method call is *pass by value*, but you are pass a **reference** that *passed as value* in parameter of *putSomethingInTheMap*!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Map<String, Integer> insert(int wert) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", wert);
    return map;
}
```

This part is the mistake because what you are doing here is, for every insert operation in a map you are creating a new map ( that will be empty ofcourse) and adding a value in this map and returning this map. 
Now

```
myMap = insert(value);
```

call will always get a map with only 1 value every time he makes an insert operation.

**Fix:**
You don't need to create a new map in `insert( int wert )`, you just need to call `put()` of java map. Code for solution is already posted by @Maurice Perry